# How to populate File Description Field programmatically?

Tags: entities

Hello I'm migrating data to my website and will like to populate File Description programatically so files display the same names on the previous website.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide more details about how you plan to do the migration (which version of Drupal?  which modules?  from what kind of CMS/solution?) and how you will be storing the files within Drupal (public/private, attached to nodes/entities, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's from a custom MySQL CMS to Drupal 7. Now I've done all my mapping and it works fine.
The only problem am facing is if I could map the file description to drupal's file field description.
In the old system files are displayed with users own description rather than the raw file name, so I'll like to map that description to drupal's field description. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to work out exactly what you mean, but the description for a file field is contained in the field tables (`field_data_field_name` and `field_revision_field_name`) in a column like `field_name_description`. You can link that back to the file with the `field_name_fid` column in the same table

Comment: Are you using Migrate module or Feeds?